# Update field inside a nested JSON object based on key using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file with the below format

```
{
    "l1":"",
    "values":{
        "id1":{
            "name":"abc",
            "enabled":"true"

        },
        "id2":{
            "name":"def",
            "enabled":"true"
        },
        "id3":{
            "name":"jjj"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add/update the enabled status of the json object based on the parent key.
so,eg: I have a file with below contents.

```
id1 false
id2 true
id3 false
id4 false
```

I want my output to look like below:

```
{
    "l1":"",
    "values":{
        "id1":{
            "name":"abc",
            "enabled":"false"

        },
        "id2":{
            "name":"def",
            "enabled":"true"
        },
        "id3":{
            "name":"jjj",
            "enabled":"false"
        }
    }
}
```

jq version:1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a mapping of the ids you want to update and the value to update to. Then use that mapping to update the corresponding values.

```
$ jq --argjson m '{"id1":"false","id2":"true","id3":"false","id4":"false"}' '
.values |= with_entries(.value.enabled = $m[.key])
' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This response addresses the issue regarding the conversion of the true/false text file to JSON.  That could be achieved in a stand-alone fashion by piping the text file to:

```
jq -nR '
  ([inputs |capture("(?<key>.*) (?<value>(true|false)) *$")
    | select(.value | fromjson | type == "boolean") ]
    | from_entries)'
```

Or, better, @JeffMercado's filter can be combined with the above, e.g. like so:

```
jq -nR --argfile in input.json '
  ([inputs |capture("(?<key>.*) (?<value>(true|false)) *$")
    | select(.value | fromjson | type == "boolean") ]
   | from_entries) as $dict
  | $in
  | .values |= with_entries(.value.enabled = $dict[.key])                   
'
```

(Yes, `--argfile` has been deprecated, so feel free to use your preferred alternative.)

If you wanted `enabled` to be boolean (i.e., `true` or `false`), you could simply add `| map_values(fromjson)` immediately after the call to `from_entries`.